# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q})$ with parameters $p$ and $q$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q})$. How to find conditions of convergency?

My idea was : approximate function to $\frac{1}{n^m}$ and analyze it. But after simplifying the numerator became awful and I got stuck. Any ideas ?

Comment: $1+\zeta(p)-\zeta(q)$

Comment: @MyGlasses I guess we could replace parts of the series if it's converge? Because there is Riemann theorem

Comment: What Riemann theorem says?

Comment: @MyGlasses if sum conditionally converges then for any $A \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ there is a permutation of elements, which give us this sum ($\sum = A$)

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-p} = \int_1^N x^{-p} dx + \mathcal{O}(N^{-p}) = \frac{N^{1-p}-1}{1-p}+ \mathcal{O}(N^{-p})$$ (it is obvious for $p > 0$ and it stays true for $p \in \mathbb{C}, \Re(p) > 0$ since $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-p} = \int_1^{N+1} \lfloor x\rfloor^{-p} dx$)

Comment: @MyGlasses we could replace elements only in partial sum.

Comment: @reuns actually I forgot about integral test.. we could consider it as $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} - \frac{1}{x^q}$, am I right ?

Comment: I forgot an $\mathcal{O}(1)$ term :D Why not reprove the integral test ? Start from $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-p} = \int_1^{N+1} \lfloor x\rfloor^{-p} dx$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k^{p}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^q}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^{p}}-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k^{q}}$$
Observe that this series is absolutely convergent of $p, q\gt 1$ and it can be telescope when $p=q.$

Now consider the other possibilities $p\ge1, q\lt1$ and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the cases which are not covered in the other answer by Nil.

If $p <0$ or $q<0$, then the series diverges (by the limit test since the terms do not tend to zero, except when $p=q >-1$, in which case the $n^{th}$ partial sum telescopes to $n^{-p}$ which diverges). Therefore we can assume that $p,q \geq 0$ from now onward.

Suppose that $p \leq 1$ and $q>p$. Then $(n+1)^{-q} \leq \frac{1}{2} n^{-p}$ for large enough values of $n$, since $n^{p}(n+1)^{-q} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Thus $n^{-p} - (n+1)^{-q} \geq \frac{1}{2} n^{-p}$ for large enough $n$, which implies that $\sum_n (n^{-p} - (n+1)^{-q}) \geq \frac{1}{2} \sum_n n^{-p}=+ \infty$ since $p\leq 1$. So the series diverges.

Now suppose that $p \leq 1$ and $q<p$. A similar argument then shows that $n^{-p}-(n+1)^{-q} \leq -\frac{1}{2} (n+1)^{-q}$ for large enough $n$, and hence $\sum_n (n^{-p} - (n+1)^{-q}) \leq -\frac{1}{2} \sum_n (n+1)^{-q}=- \infty$, since $q<1$. So the series diverges.

This proves that if $p \leq 1$ and $q \neq p$ then the series diverges.

Similar argument shows that if $q \leq 1$ and $q \neq p$ then the series diverges.

Therefore the series converges if and only if $p,q>1$ or $p=q \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is tedious casechecking:

1. If $p\leq 0$ or $q\leq 0$

   - If ($p<0$ and $q\geq 0$) or ($q<0$ and $p\geq 0$): $\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}$ does not go to $0$, hence divergence
   - If $p=0$ and $q=0$: $\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}=0$, hence convergence
   - If ($p=0$ and $q> 0$) or ($q=0$ and $p> 0$): $\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}$ does not go to $0$, hence divergence
   - If ($p=0$ and $q< 0$) or ($q=0$ and $p< 0$): $\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}$ does not go to $0$, hence divergence
   - If  $p<0$ and $q< 0$:

     - If $p\neq q$, $\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}\sim \pm n^{\max(|p|,|q|)}$ which goes to $\pm\infty$, hence divergence.
     - If $p=q$, the series telescopes to $1-(N+1)^{-p}\to -\infty$, hence divergence.
2. If $p> 0$ and $q> 0$

Note that $$\frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}=\frac{1}{n^p}-\frac{1}{n^q}+\frac{q}{n^{q+1}}+o\left( \frac{1}{n^{q+1}} \right)$$

Since $q+1>1$, the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^q}$ converges if and only if $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^p}-\frac{1}{n^q}$ converges.

As a result, if $p=q$, the series converges. If $p\neq q$:

- if $\min(p,q)\leq 1$, the series diverges.
- if $\min(p,q)> 1$ the series converges.

---

To sum up, the series converges if and only if

- ($p=0$ and $q=0$)

or

- ($p=q >0$)

or

- ($p> 0$ and $q> 0$ and $\min(p,q)> 1$ )

which rewrites more compactly as

- ($p=q \geq0$)

or

- ($\min(p,q)> 1$ )

Comment: No, the series converges by telescope whenever $p=q \geq 0$, for example when $p=q=1$.

Comment: @Shalop fixed..